# Gcloud initialized to wrong project

Tags: linux, npm, google-api, archlinux

When trying to run my Nodejs application which uses the Google-Cloud-Video-Intelligence API, I am getting an error:

```
(node:20730) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: Cloud Video Intelligence API has not been used in project firebase-cli before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/videointelligence.googleapis.com/overview?project=firebase-cli then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.
at new createStatusError (/home/warcram/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:64:15)
at /home/warcram/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:583:15
(node:20730) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:20730) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.e
```

Now, this would be fixable if I was using the firebase-cli project, however this has since been deleted. I am now trying to use a separate project. I used gcloud init in the same directory for the new project, however when running the application I still get the same errors.

Is there anyway that I can uninitialize the firebase-cli project and continue with my new one?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Figured the issue out, I needed to set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable to the initialization json file. I did this and my program worked using the correct project. Thanks for any views, hope this helps in the future.